# Find new coordinates after the rotating an image in 90/180/270 in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, rotation, geometry

I am having an image(w:10, h:15) and some drawings(a rectangle A(6,4), W:2, H:4) in a XML file. I need to find out new coordinates of A (ie: A'(11,6)) after 90/180/270 degree rotation of the image in C#.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayfrf.png)

[After 90 degree rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqCbH.png)

I tried following code, but I am getting A' relative to original image. I need A' coordinates in rotated image.

```
public static PointF RotatePoint(double x, double y, double pageHeight, double pageWidth, int rotateAngle)
    {
        //Calculate rotate angle in radian
        var angle = rotateAngle * Math.PI / 180.0f;

        //Find rotate orgin
        double rotateOrginX = pageWidth / 2;
        double rotateOrginY = pageHeight / 2;

        var cosA = Math.Cos(angle);
        var sinA = Math.Sin(angle);

        var pX = (float)(cosA * (x - rotateOrginX) - sinA * (y - rotateOrginY) + rotateOrginX);
        var pY = (float)(sinA * (x - rotateOrginX) + cosA * (y - rotateOrginY) + rotateOrginY);

        Console.WriteLine($"Rotate {rotateAngle}\tX: {pX}\tY: {pY}");

        return new PointF { X = pX, Y = pY };
    }
```

Comment: At the least you should try to code this yourself and add the code of your "Best Attempt" as a part of your question. [mcve]

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

If the rotations are only ever 90°, 180°, or 270° using `Math.Sin()` and `Cos()` is overkill.

At 90° rotations the coordinates can be manipulated quite easily...

```
W  : Image width before rotation
H  : Image height before rotation
x  : X coordinate in image before rotation
x' : X coordinate in image after rotation
y  : Y coordinate in image before rotation
y' : Y coordinate in image after rotation

For 0° CCW:
x' = x
y' = y

For 90° CCW:
x' = y
y' = W - x

For 180° CCW/CW:
x' = W - x
y' = H - y

For 270° CCW:
x' = H - y
y' = x
```

**In C#:**

```csharp
public static PointF RotatePoint(float x, float y, int pageWidth, int pageHeight, int degrees)
{
    switch(degrees)
    {
        case 0: return new PointF(x,y);
        case 90: return new PointF(y, pageWidth - x);
        case 180: return new PointF(pageWidth - x, pageHeight - y);
        case 270: return new PointF(pageHeight - y, x);
        default:
            // Either throw ArgumentException or implement the universal logic with Sin(), Cos()
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity in this answer. Just want to leave a reminder to swap 90 with 270 when rotating clockwise.